# Get duplicate on single column after distinct across multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
name | id
-----------
A 1
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 3
D 3
F 2
```

I want to return id's 1 and 2 because they are duplicate on names. I don't want to return 3, because it is distinct for D 3.

Basically, I'm thinking of doing a query to first get a distinct pairing, so the above reduces to

```
name | id
-----------
A 1
B 2
C 1
D 3
F 2
```

And then doing a duplicate find on the id column. However, I'm struggling to find the correct syntax to construct that query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the result you want by using a `GROUP BY` along with a `HAVING` clause that counts the distinct names. The `HAVING` clause will filter for those ids that have more than one distinct name:

```
select id
from Table1
group by id
having count(distinct name) > 1
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d3c96/1/0)